# Linux Mint: Splitting disks to 3 partitions

Tags: filesystems, partition

I have recently bought a 2TB HDD drive, to install in my PC.  After installation, I plan to have 3 partitions:

- **OS**: Partition on SSD drive (240GB) that will contain the Operating System files, binaries + some important applications;
- **Software**: Partition on HDD, containing applications and games;
- **Files**: Partition on HDD, with all the files (photos, text files, videos, etc).

I am not sure what to do with my home folder. Is it a good idea to split it to **Software** and **Files**?

Also how much memory should I allocate to the **Software** partition and how much to **Files** one (again, they are on HDD drive with 2TB of disk space)?

I use Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Comment: Welcome! What are the reasons you want to do such partitioning? You won't run out of space if the whole system in one partition, which may happen if you make separate partitions. Your home folder is not intended to store software, but rather your personal data. In this case, you can make a separate partition of your home, no need to split it into several parts.

Comment: You partition the disk not the filesystems. Once you have a partition, *then* you apply a filesystem to it (EXT4, NTFS, etc).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Hello. I want to split it into partitions because it will just be comfortable for me. What does making a partition of home means? Also sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity also im not splitting a drive into 3 partitions byt 2 drives into 3 partitions and that is why I said "filesystem"

Comment: When you install linux, you have the option of mounting some root folders (like home, var, boot) into different partitions. You can also do this later, but it's easier to do it in the installation process.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me

Comment: "byt 2 drives into 3 partitions" it sounds like [LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for) partitioning, but I'm not sure that's what you are aiming for

Comment: Nope, I mean common partitioning - splitting one of drives to 2 partitions and leaving another one with one partition. Also is there any gui app that will allow me to mount those root folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your planned partitioning scheme is that it does not conform to the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml). I don't know to what extent Linux Mint complies with the standard, but it's quite likely that it aims to be mostly compliant.

What this means in your particular case, is that applications are installed by the Mint package manager into predefined locations; Ex. Some files will be stored in /usr/bin while others in /etc, while others in /usr/share... and so on. This means it's not possible to install some programs in one partition and other programs in another. Notable exceptions are third-party programs installed with scripts (usually installed in /opt) and [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) applications.

I think a suitable partitioning scheme for you is as follows:

## SSD

1. /boot (or /boot/efi) - The Linux Mint boot partition.
2. / - Your root filesystem

## HDD

1. /home - The partition for all user files. This should work for Steam games as well.